# Performing one action on multiple tabs(from jtabbedpane) created in a class

Tags: java, swing, tabs

I have created a gui, this gui uses a jtabbed pane. I have an array which contains the names of each tab. I use

```
for (String locale : langList){
    LocaleTab tab = new LocaleTab();
    tab.buildTab(locale);
    localeTabs.add(locale, tab.getTabPanel());
}
```

in my main class to create the tabs. On each tab I have a jtextarea and a jtable as well as two buttons, one for running an action on that specific tab and another for clearing the contents in the table and textarea of that locale. This works perfectly.

My problem is, I can run and clear all the contents on each tab individually, I can't figure out how to do this for all tabs at once. I have a main clear and run button, which when pressed will clear all textarea and table data on all locales or run the action on all locales at once.

I thought I could do the following in an action listener for my clear button:

```
for (String locale : langList){
    LocaleTab tab = new LocaleTab();
    tab.clearTab();
}
```

but it didn't work. Do I need to pass the object tab to my method to work on the tabs all at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggested solution does not work since you create new `LocaleTab` objects in your action listener. So you will be clearing the tab of `LocaleTab` instances which are not present in your UI (and which no longer exists as soon as you leave that method due to the scope of that variable).

Instead your listener should have access to the `LocaleTab` instances which you originally created.

*Note*

Small remark on seeing this code. Why would you create a UI for all supported languages at the same time. An end-user typically uses the application in one language, so why do you need that extra UI. Why not only creating UI for the appropriate language, hence bypassing the problem you currently face

Comment: The program is actually for scraping webpages for links. The tool will be for link checking on webpages that are localised. So each tab is for the same webpage but in differnt locales, en-us, fr-fr etc. So one user will actually be using the different tabs.

Probably a stupid question but how would I go about giving my actionlistener access to the object? Would I have to pass the object to the actionListener and if so how?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your code didn't work was already mentioned by @Robin (+1).

To expand on @Robin's answer I suggest the following:

1. Create a method which will take as its parameter the tabs you want to clear, name it e.g. `clearTabs(List<LocaleTab> tabs)`.
2. You could store references to all created tabs, e.g. in a global variable (a list), called e.g. `tabs`.
3. The action listener on your clear button should in the `actionPerformed` method, call the clearing method, for example, as below. (I would recommend for you to switch to using [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) instead of an `ActionListener`).

   ```
   Action clearAction = new AbstractAction("Clear Tabs"){
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           clearTabs(tabs);
       }
   };
   ```

**EDIT**
The body of  `clearTabs` method.

```
void clearTabs(List<LocaleTab> tabs){
   for (LocaleTab tab: tabs)
      tab.clearTab();
}
```

Comment: When you say store a reference to all tabs I created what exactly do you mean? I already have an array of the locales for which tabs I will be creating, is that array enough? Or should I be storing something else?

Comment: I mean a reference to a list of LocaleTab objects. The array you are referring to (langList) has only Strings, right? Also please see edit for the body of the `clearTabs` method.